# how to add line plot to a stacked bar plot in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset like in the image attached, and I want to put the percentage of the red portion over total bar in the same plot, that is, I want to put a line plot of percent vs year in the same plot of stacked bar plt.  However, I can get second axes shown but no line. How to get this to work?

Thanks!

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
test[['WON','LOST']].plot(kind='bar',stacked=True,figsize=(10,7),color=['#E84545','#2B2E4A'],ax=ax)
fmt = '${x:,.0f}'
tick = ticker.StrMethodFormatter(fmt)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tick) 
plt.xticks(rotation=25,fontsize=18)
plt.yticks(fontsize=18)
plt.xlabel('Year', fontsize=24)
plt.ylabel("Sum of System Revenue",fontsize=24)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(test['percent'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: [matplotlib lineplot to stacked bar](https://www.google.com/search?q=matplotlib+lineplot+to+stacked+bar+site:stackoverflow.com&sxsrf=ALeKk00re1vgwdg0zws9OVrmI4pG_IBz9A:1596510436703&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwieu9bryIDrAhVTpZ4KHS6EAdsQrQIoBHoECAcQBQ&biw=1920&bih=975)

Comment: Thanks for your help!. Indeed this post solved the problem. The key is to reset index... I did search for quite a while about "add line plot to bar plot", but never found this post.... seems that I need to improve my googling skills too. :P    Thanks.